# Dividing date/time elements displayed from sql call, into sperate divs?

Tags: sql, date, time

This sql call,

```
<div class="dateOnAd"><?php print $row['dttm_modified']; ?></div>
```

outputs:
2012-05-22 15:07:28.

I need to figure out a way to divide the output into different divs

```
<div class="example-date">
   <span class="day">31</span> 
   <span class="month">July</span> 
   <span class="year">2009</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't do the separation in the query? i.e. return the day, month and year as separate fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="example-date">
    <span class="day"><?php echo date('d', $row['ddtm_modified']); ?></span>
    <span class="month"><?php echo date('F', $row['ddtm_modified']); ?></span>
    <span class="year"><?php echo date('Y', $row['ddtm_modified']); ?></span>
</div>
```

You can read more about the `date()` function here: [`date`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).